# First step analysis of the variance of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be discrete random variables.
Let $Z$ be $X$ rsp. $Y$ with probability $p$ rsp. $q$, that is: $P(Z = z) := p \cdot P(X = z) + q \cdot P(Y = z)$.

According to my computations, the first step analysis of the variance yields:$$
Var(Z) = p \cdot Var(X) + q \cdot Var(Y) + p \cdot q \cdot (E(X) - E(Y))^2
$$

Is this formula correct? I would like to have a second opinion, or a reference.

Slight abuse of terminology: For the sake of simplicity, there is no actual "first step" here, but the case analysis remains essentially the same. At least I believe so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you only want to be a bit more precise/formal? By your description, $Z=BX+(1-B)Y$, where $B$ is a Bernoulli random variable with $\mathbb{P}(B=1)=p=1-q$ independent of $X$ and $Y$. Then for any $k>0$, you get $Z^k=BX^k+(1-B)Y^k$, so 
$$\mathbb{E}(Z^k)=p\mathbb{E}(X^k)+q\mathbb{E}(Y^k).$$

In particular, using the formula for $k\in\{1,2\}$ gives

$$\begin{split}
Var(Z)
&=\mathbb{E}(Z^2)-\mathbb{E}(Z)^2\\
&=[p\mathbb{E}(X^2)+q\mathbb{E}(Y^2)]-[p\mathbb{E}(X)+q\mathbb{E}(Y)]^2\\
&=p\cdot Var(X)+q\cdot Var(Y^2)-(p^2-p)\mathbb{E}(X)^2-(q^2-q)\mathbb{E}(Y)^2-2pq\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)\\
&=p\cdot Var(X)+q\cdot Var(Y^2)+pq(\mathbb{E}(X)-\mathbb{E}(Y))^2.
\end{split}$$

Is this what you were after?

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted. Even slightly more: I learned from your usage of Bernoulli variables.

Comment: That's great to know!